# How to add data to a field based on other fields in a SQL database

Tags: sql, sqlite, view, count, window-functions

I have an SQLite table called `wcvp` constructed from a csv file downloaded from the World Check List of Vascular Plants (see https://wcvp.science.kew.org/ and http://sftp.kew.org/pub/data-repositories/WCVP/). When I run this query:

```
sqlite> SELECT kew_id, genus, species, infraspecies 
        FROM wcvp 
        WHERE genus = 'Quercus' 
          AND species = 'robur' 
          AND taxonomic_status = 'Accepted';
```

I get this result:

| kew_id | genus | species | infraspecies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 304293-2 | Quercus | robur |  |
| 77189540-1 | Quercus | robur | broteroana |
| 77189379-1 | Quercus | robur | brutia |
| 77189383-1 | Quercus | robur | imeretina |
| 60459295-2 | Quercus | robur | pedunculiflo |
| 77171868-1 | Quercus | robur | robur |

I want to add a column to the table (which has hundreds of thousands of rows in it) called `number_of_infraspecies` which would look like this:

| kew_id | genus | species | infraspecies | number_of_infraspecies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 304293-2 | Quercus | robur |  | 5 |
| 77189540-1 | Quercus | robur | broteroana | NULL |
| 77189379-1 | Quercus | robur | brutia | NULL |
| 77189383-1 | Quercus | robur | imeretina | NULL |
| 60459295-2 | Quercus | robur | pedunculiflo | NULL |
| 77171868-1 | Quercus | robur | robur | NULL |

Alternatively I could construct a new table with two columns: `kew_id` as a foreign key and `number_of_infraspecies` as the other column.

Whichever approach I take I can only think of a procedure which would result in making a separate query for every row of the `wcvp` table or at least those rows which do not have a value in the infraspecies column (AND taxonomic_status = 'Accepted').

Is there a way of doing it with one or just a few queries?

Comment: Have you thought what will happen if you add a new row in the table for a new plant or delete a row? You will have to update that number. Or is it a static table?

Comment: I had not thought about that although I think I would be OK to have it static. I would need to be able to generate it again every time WCVP issued an updated version of the database which I think is weekly. Is there any formal way of creating and handling static tables other than just not altering them in your code logic?

Comment: I have already posted an answer where I propose the use of a VIEW. You can check it.

Comment: I am amazed that it can be done with so little code! It is good to have a solution to work towards understanding as I find directed learning better than just generally trying to get better at SQL (although I should do more of that as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `VIEW` that returns the column `number_of_infraspecies`:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT kew_id, genus, species, infraspecies,
       CASE 
         WHEN infraspecies IS NULL 
           THEN COUNT(infraspecies) OVER (PARTITION BY genus, species)
       END number_of_infraspecies
FROM wcvp
WHERE taxonomic_status = 'Accepted';
```

and then select from that `VIEW` specific `genus` and `species`:

```
SELECT kew_id, genus, species, infraspecies, number_of_infraspecies
FROM my_view
WHERE genus = 'Quercus' AND species = 'robur';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=77844430d894aa05332449cd01706715).

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `count(*)` as a window function:

```
SELECT kew_id, genus, species, infraspecies,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY genus, species) as infra_species
FROM wcvp
WHERE genus = 'Quercus' AND species = 'robur' AND
      taxonomic_status = 'Accepted';
```

Comment: thanks! I will look into that as well as @forpas answer.